# Robolectric test not running for project having own Application class

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have followed steps as mentioned Robolectric  http://robolectric.org/eclipse-quick-start/
I am able to successfully run the test as per steps provided. For a fresh new Project and Test project.

But when I followed same steps for my existing project, then nothing happens only a warning is being shown and test gets terminated.

[image]

My existing app is for target android-15 and I am using `robolectric-2.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

P.S. I have created a new Java Project for my existing project.

**UPDATE**

After hours of debugging I found that, if I remove `android:name="com.myapp.bl.MyApplication` from AndroidManifest, then its starts executing tests.

```
<application
    android:name="com.myapp.bl.MyApplication" 
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Is there any addition flag or setting, that I have to pass Robolectric, so that it 
understands MyApplication class.

Regards,
Yuvi

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, there was an exception in MyApplication class. If that exception occurs then application was getting closed.